# Ionic with capacitor and Android not running emulator in IntelliJ

Tags: android, ionic-framework, intellij-idea, capacitor

I ran npx doctor and npx cap sync

```
   Capacitor Doctor   

 Latest Dependencies:

  @capacitor/cli: 2.2.1
  @capacitor/core: 2.2.1
  @capacitor/android: 2.2.1
  @capacitor/electron: 2.2.1
  @capacitor/ios: 2.2.1

Installed Dependencies:

  @capacitor/cli 2.2.1
  @capacitor/core 2.2.1
  @capacitor/android 2.2.1
  @capacitor/ios 2.2.1
  @capacitor/electron not installed

[success] Android looking great! 
  Found 0 Capacitor plugins for ios:
[success] iOS looking great! 
~/projects/private/growbox: ()$ npx cap open android
[info] Opening Android project at /Users//projects/private/growbox/android
~/projects/private/growbox: ()$ npx cap sync  
✔ Copying web assets from mobile to android/app/src/main/assets/public in 5.45s
✔ Copying native bridge in 10.89ms
✔ Copying capacitor.config.json in 8.76ms
✔ copy in 5.50s
✔ Updating Android plugins in 15.83ms
  Found 0 Capacitor plugins for android:
✔ update android in 86.12ms
✔ Copying web assets from mobile to ios/App/public in 5.37s
✔ Copying native bridge in 3.78ms
✔ Copying capacitor.config.json in 4.42ms
✔ copy in 5.41s
✔ Updating iOS plugins in 15.84ms
  Found 0 Capacitor plugins for ios:
✔ Updating iOS native dependencies with "pod install" (may take several minutes) in 26.92s
✔ update ios in 26.98s
✔ copy in 1.30ms
✔ update web in 5.00μp
Sync finished in 38.021s
```

This is what I got and after that I ran: `npx cap open android`

```
Got: [info] Opening Android project at /Users//projects/private/growbox/android
```

And nothing happening.
I have emulator running and everything properly installed and I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate latest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Capacitor open command try to open Android Studio, if you use IntelliJ, you'll have to open it manually.

There is a feature request for opening different IDEs https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/3242

Comment: How it is possible to open it manually, there's no example of how to run the project manually. Can you refer me or give me the code to do it?

Comment: The android folder contains an android project, so open it the same way you open an android project in IntelliJ

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on Linux (Windows below), to open in IntelliJ Ultimate, simply edit the capacitor.config.json file and add the linuxAndroidStudioPath as another top-level property of the JSON file:

```
{
     "appId": "com.foo.app",
     "appName": "FooBar",
     "bundledWebRuntime": false,
 ...
     "linuxAndroidStudioPath": "/opt/idea-IU-201.7846.76/bin/idea.sh"
}
```

Run

```
npx cap open android
```

If IntelliJ is already open, then it gives the familiar dialog for opening in the current window or in a new window.

If you're running on Windows, it looks like the option is windowsAndroidStudioPath

The Windows parameter was taken from [the capacitor configuration page](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm using Mac OSX can you assist with that?

Comment: @IamStalker in hunting the source, it looks like code has, in the last 3 days, been merged into the main branch and now uses the STUDIO_PATH environment variable. What this means in terms of release (e.g., if it is a GA release), I don't know? In the coming week I'll check and update my answer accordingly. If you have any information regarding what release it is available in, please advise. https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/blob/d71e6d5e841c68073868c977b0aa1affbab30553/cli/src/config.ts#L167

Comment: Seems like it's constant variable, without any change.

Comment: Do you mean process.env? That gets the environment variable from your system. You'll have to set it first, of course. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-process-env-property/